# Detecting names using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have used nltk to detect people's name. I'm trying to analyze book "Harry Potter". Using this library I'm usually get many other words (eg Aunt, Page, Dont...). Also it detect some names strangely: 'Aunt Petunia ' at the start, but ['Aunt ', 'Petunia '] at the end.

I use following code:

```py
def find_person(self, sentence: list): # sentence - list of words
    persons = list() 
    nltk_results = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(' '.join(sentence)))) # tokenizing sentence
    for result in nltk_results:
        if type(result) == Tree:
            name = ''
            for result_leaf in result.leaves():
                name += result_leaf[0] + ' '
            persons.append(name) # appending names
       
    return persons # return list of names
```

Comment: Why would this pick out names?  The names you mentioned are also English words, but what about "Ron" and "Hermione"?